# How to use [FromHeader] attribute with custom model binding in Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to add many custom headers in my request. I can use something like this

```
public ActionResult Get([FromHeader, Required]string header1, [FromHeader]string  header2, ... , [FromHeader]string headerx)
{
...
...
}
```

I am not sure if it is good to use that number of parameters in one method.
I would like to use something like this

```
public class HeaderParameters 
{
  [Required]
  public string Header1 { get; set; }
  public string Header2 { get; set; }
  ...
  public string Headerx { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Get([FromHeader]HeaderParameters headerParameters)
{
  ...
  ...
}
```

But it doesn't work.

If I use [FromHeader] attribute for each property of HeaderParameters class Swagger is acting weird.

[Request example http://prntscr.com/p14kd7](http://prntscr.com/p14kd7)

```
{
  "errors": {
    "Device": [
      "The Header1 field is required."
    ]
  },
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "0HLPG9SNNJ1U2:00000001"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

There is an easier way in ASP.NET Core in .Net Core 3.1. Just put `[FromHeader]` everywhere, like this:

```
[HttpPost("multipleHeaders")]
public IActionResult Post([FromHeader] ForecastHeaders forecastHeaders)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got a forecast for city: {forecastHeaders.City}," +
                            $"temperature: {forecastHeaders.TemperatureC} and" +
                            $"description: {forecastHeaders.Description}!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }

    return new AcceptedResult();
}
```

And `ForecastHeaders` look like this:

```
public class ForecastHeaders
{
    [FromHeader]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [FromHeader]
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [FromHeader]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [FromQuery]
    public string Sorting { get; set; }
}
```

And when you send a request with Postman:
[image]

It works like a charm:
[image]

Just put `[FromHeader]` everywhere. Work with `[FromQuery]` as well.

Answer (score 10):

Was able to make it work by using `[FromHeader]` attribute on model properties and `[FromQuery]` attribute on model itself to fool model binding. Such setup allows Swagger to correctly identify each header parameter.

Controller endpoint sample:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("headers")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get([FromQuery] HeadersParameters parameters = null)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
    }
```

`HeadersParameters` declaration:

```
    public class HeadersParameters
    {
        [FromHeader]
        [Required]
        public string Header1 { get; set; }

        [FromHeader]
        public string Header2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. API is able to receive headers. But as I understand, there is an issue with Swagger. It generates the following curl ```CURL -X  ... -H "parameters: header1,string,header2,string"```

Comment: @IvanBerezhnyk Edited my answer - now it works for Swagger also. Trick was to use [FromQuery] on model itself, so then it works for GET method.

Answer (score 7):

I have created a custom attribute to avoid misunderstanding.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FromHeaderModelAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata, IModelNameProvider
{
        public BindingSource BindingSource => BindingSource.Query;

        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, final result is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("headers")]
public ActionResult<string> Get([FromHeaderModel] HeadersParameters parameters = null)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
}

public class HeadersParameters
{
    [FromHeader]
    [Required]
    public string Header1 { get; set; }

    [FromHeader]
    public string Header2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I understand this is a old post, but since there is not an accepted answer. This is also based on ASP.NET Core 6. You can combine multiple attributes Required, RegularExpression and FromHeader as shown below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserAsync
(
 [Required]
 [RegularExpression(@"[1-9]*", ErrorMessage = "Must be greater then zero.")]
 [FromHeader(Name = "x-tenant-id")] 
 long xTenantId, 
 [FromRoute] long id
)
```

How this helps someone.

Comment: I think the original post was asking how to encapsulate the parameters into a model class with properties.  I just got it to work, but I have had trouble getting it to work.  It seems to have something to do with the type of parameter and matching its name.