# Swagger UI sends multiple headers bound to a single action parameter as a single json object, rather than as multiple headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I enabled Swagger in my asp.net core 3.1 API by following the usual MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
It works fine.

The following controller works great in Postman.
**myBody** has its **Body1** and **Body2** fields bound from the POST request's json body.
**myHeader** has its **Header1** and **Header2** bound from the request's two "Header1" and "Header2" headers.

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("test")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public ActionResult Post(
            [FromHeader] MyHeaders myHeaders,
            MyBody myBody)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }

    public class MyHeaders
    {
        [FromHeader]
        public string Header1 { get; set; }

        [FromHeader]
        public string Header2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyBody
    {
        public string Body1 { get; set; }

        public string Body2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However Swagger UI only passes 1 json object for the two headers:
[swagger ui][1]

And it generates a corresponding curl command:
`curl -X POST "https://localhost:5001/test" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "myHeaders: header1,string,header2,string" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"body1\":\"string\",\"body2\":\"string\"}"`

The problem is the **-H  "myHeaders: header1,string,header2,string"** portion. Model binding sets myHeaders.Header1 and .Header2 to null, as expected, because the header is named "myHeaders".
Replacing the portion with **-H  "Header1: cat" -H  "Header2: dog" works correctly.

Asp.net is clever enough to map separate headers into a single action parameter by matching their names. But how can I get Swagger have multiple headers the UI, so its curl command works?
I know I could replace `[FromHeader] MyHeaders myHeaders` with `[FromHeader] string Header1, [FromHeader] string Header2`, but I want to avoid that. There will be dozens of actions that all receive the same set of headers.

Comment: Try one of the solutions given in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768912/how-to-use-fromheader-attribute-with-custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-2-2 It should help you.

Comment: @Harsh you nailed it, the second answer from Yura was the solution. Many thanks. Swagger UI works correctly if **[FromHeader] MyHeaders myHeaders** is changed to **[FromQuery] MyHeaders myHeaders**.  It seems crazy, but it works. I'll write up a proper answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is given in Yura's answer in [How to use [FromHeader] attribute with custom model binding in Asp.Net Core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768912/how-to-use-fromheader-attribute-with-custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-2-2)
It is to change **[FromHeader] MyHeaders myHeaders** to **[FromQuery] MyHeaders myHeaders**.
This gets Swagger UI working, even though the FromQuery seems to be contradicted by the FromHeader attribute on Header1 and Header2.

The fixed code is:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public ActionResult Post(
        [FromQuery] MyHeaders myHeaders, // FromHeader is changed to FromQuery
        MyBody myBody)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class MyHeaders // unchanged
{
    [FromHeader]
    public string Header1 { get; set; }

    [FromHeader]
    public string Header2 { get; set; }
}
```