# ASP.NET Core : HttpPost : Multiple object, same interface. How to use polymorphisme with custom binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have multiple Object with different structure, but each time i make a save on these objects, i want to carry out common control actions because these objects are in fact "content objects" of a similar process.

imagine in UI user can do tasks, he must enter different data depend on task but we stay in the same "process".

i want to avoid multiple HttPut Route, so i want something like this :

```
        [HttpPut("{processId}/content")]
        public ActionResult SaveContent(IContent content)
        {
            //Do something with the processID like security controll
            //Now i can do the different save 
        }
```

i want to have an instance of my specific object, i can determine type with a property "ContentType"

i would like to have a custombinder to do something like this :

```
if(content.GetContent==ContentA)
{
return ContentA with all properties binded from body
}

else if(content.GetContent==ContentB)
{
return ContentB with all properties binded from body
}
```

i dont want to map properties manually, i want to work as if I had put "ContentA" or "ContentB" in [FromBody] parameter.

i just want to avoid this:

```
    [HttpPut("{processId}/content-a")]
    public ActionResult SaveContentA(ContentA contentA)
    {
        //Do something with the processID like security control
        //Now i can save contentA
    }

    [HttpPut("{processId}/content-b")]
    public ActionResult SaveContentB(ContentB contentb)
    {
        //Do something with the processID like security control
        //Now i can save contentB
    }
```

I can have 20+ different content, that's a lot of different routes (of course I have different services behind that do different actions depending on content A or B but I would like to avoid as many routes).

I looked at the side of the custombinding but I did not manage to do what I wanted.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you put some information about the `content` in http header?

Comment: Even if i have information about content, how Can i have my object instance ? Each content has différent structure

Comment: If you use http header you should change `[FromBody]` to `[FromHeader]` attribute. You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768912/how-to-use-fromheader-attribute-with-custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-2-2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure if I understand your requirement correctly. From what you shared, the `IContent` is some kind of a base interface which contains a common set of members (properties, ...) for all the derived types (which should be well-known). So it's actually a scenario of polymorphic model binding and can be implemented by using a customer `IModelBinder` as demonstrated in a basic example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#polymorphic-model-binding

I've adjusted that example a bit to make it cleaner with more separate responsibility and better naming. The following code is not tested at all. Because the main logic is basically the same as from the example in the given link above:

```
//the marker interface to indicate the model should be polymorphically bound.
//you can replace this with your IContent
public interface IPolymorphModel { }
//a separate resolver to help resolve actual model type from ModelBindingContext
//(kind of separating responsibility
public interface IPolymorphTypeResolver
{
    Type ResolveType(ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext);
}
//a separate types provider to get all derived types from a base type/interface
public interface IPolymorphTypeProvider
{
    IEnumerable<Type> GetDerivedTypesFrom<T>();
}

//the custom model binder for polymorphism
public class PolymorphModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    readonly IDictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata ModelMetadata, IModelBinder Binder)> _bindersByType;
    readonly IPolymorphTypeResolver _polymorphTypeResolver;
    public PolymorphModelBinder(IDictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata,IModelBinder)> bindersByType,
        IPolymorphTypeResolver polymorphTypeResolver)
    {
        _bindersByType = bindersByType;
        _polymorphTypeResolver = polymorphTypeResolver;
    }        
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelType = _polymorphTypeResolver.ResolveType(bindingContext);
        if(modelType == null || 
          !_bindersByType.TryGetValue(modelType, out var binder))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return;
        }            
        //create new binding context with the concrete/actual model type
        var actualBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(bindingContext.ActionContext,
            bindingContext.ValueProvider,
            binder.ModelMetadata,
            null,
            bindingContext.ModelName);
        await binder.Binder.BindModelAsync(actualBindingContext);
        //set back the result to the original bindingContext
        bindingContext.Result = actualBindingContext.Result;
        if (actualBindingContext.Result.IsModelSet)
        {
            bindingContext.ValidationState[bindingContext.Result] = new ValidationStateEntry {
                Metadata = binder.ModelMetadata
            };
        }
    }
}

//the custom model binder provider for polymorphism
public class PolymorphModelBinderProvider<T> : IModelBinderProvider
{
    readonly IPolymorphTypeResolver _polymorphTypeResolver;
    readonly IPolymorphTypeProvider _polymorphTypeProvider;
    public PolymorphModelBinderProvider(IPolymorphTypeResolver polymorphTypeResolver,
           IPolymorphTypeProvider polymorphTypeProvider)
    {
        _polymorphTypeResolver = polymorphTypeResolver;
        _polymorphTypeProvider = polymorphTypeProvider;
    }
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(context.Metadata.ModelType)) return null;
        //prepare the list of the well-known derived types
        var derivedTypes = _polymorphTypeProvider.GetDerivedTypesFrom<T>();
        var binders = derivedTypes.ToDictionary(e => e, 
                                                e =>
                                                {
                                                    var modelMetadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(e);
                                                    return (modelMetadata, context.CreateBinder(modelMetadata));
                                                }
                                    );
        return new PolymorphModelBinder(binders, _polymorphTypeResolver);
    }
}
```

Here is the default implementation for a `IPolymorphTypeResolver` which basically depends on an `IValueProvider` from the `ModelBindingContext` (which is just like what used in the  Microsoft's example):

```
public class DefaultPolymorphTypeResolver : IPolymorphTypeResolver
{
    public Type ResolveType(ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext)
    {
        var contentTypeValueKey = ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(modelBindingContext.ModelName, "ContentType");
        var contentType = modelBindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(contentTypeValueKey).FirstValue;
        switch (contentType)
        {
            case "whatever ...":
                return ...;                    
            //...
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you store the `contentType` in header or some other sources, just implement it your own way, here for the content type stored in the request header:

```
public class DefaultPolymorphTypeResolver : IPolymorphTypeResolver {
   public Type ResolveType(ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext) {
       var contentType = modelBindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
       switch (contentType)
        {                                 
            //...
            default:
                return null;
        }
   }
}
```

Here is the default implementation of `IPolymorphTypeProvider`:

```
public class PolymorphContentTypeProvider : IPolymorphTypeProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetDerivedTypesFrom<T>()
    {
        return new List<Type> { /* your logic to populate the list ... */ };
    }
}
```

Now we configure it to register everything needed including the `PolymorphModelBinderProvider` and your specific implementation of `IPolymorphTypeResolver` and `IPolymorphTypeProvider`:

```
//in ConfigureServices
services.AddSingleton<IPolymorphTypeResolver, DefaultPolymorphTypeResolver>();
services.AddSingleton<IPolymorphTypeProvider, PolymorphContentTypeProvider>();

services.AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
        .Configure((MvcOptions o, 
                    IPolymorphTypeResolver typeResolver, 
                    IPolymorphTypeProvider typesProvider) =>
         {
             o.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new PolymorphModelBinderProvider<IPolymorphModel>(typeResolver, typesProvider));
        });
```

Comment: maybe I can't explain my problem.

IContent is just a marker interface to identify what is a "content" object.

but I found a potential solution, by taking a JObject as a parameter of my controller.

i call database with ID of my resource, i get the "content type" and after i use JObject.ToObject depending of contentType

Comment: @digofwall even if it's a marker interface, it's just like a base type which may contain no element. My code above uses `IPolymorphModel` which can be replaced by your `IContent` (already commented in the code). The code should help bind the concrete model (from the request) to the `IContent`. Of course the code later which processs that `IContent` should be aware of its actual type to handle correctly. Do you have any problem with my code?

Comment: @digofwall what you said about `JObject` ... does not matter. It's just a way to send the `content-type` and from that you deserialize back an instance of that type. That way you really deserialize the model manually and should better end up using a custom `IModelBinder` anyway. Actually you can send a long the content type in `header` or expose it via a property of `IContent`, it's not necessary to use a separate parameter for the content-type. The content type is just like an id from which you can map to the actual `Type` on the server side code (depending on your design).

Comment: but the problem is not to get the content type because i have it via {processId}. When i have my processId i call Database, and i have a ProcessObject, that contains my contentType, so after i can transform body request into model.
I Just want to transform my JSON into Object, i dont want to create a new object, i just want to transform json into object without map properties

Comment: @digofwall I know the main part is to deserialize back the instance from its contenttype. That sounds simple but once you want it neat & nice like `SaveContent(IContent content)` you don't have better option than implement a custom `IModelBinder` as shown in my answer. I don't understand what's wrong with this answer. You simply said something that you have another approach but really that's just how you deserialize it, using a custom `IModelBinder` is always the way you go.

Comment: @digofwall `IContent` is still abstract, it can be whatever you want and you know how to transform it into the object you want (that's the detailed implementation), but the shell / framework (as shown in my answer) is always usable. Of course if you don't want to go that way (not even use a custom `IModelBinder`), you can just pass in a string like `SaveContent(int contentId, string content)`  and manually deserialize it to the object you want.